# Error in calculate_centralities(net, include = "Information Centrality") : The input is not an igraph object or may not be connected

Tags: r, sna

I am trying to get Information centrality by using package *CINNA*.

```
library(CINNA)

my.data <- data.frame(fun$screen_name, fun$retweet_name)

net <- graph.data.frame(my.data, directed = T)

calculate_centralities(net, include = "Information Centrality")
```

> Error in `calculate_centralities(net, include = "Information Centrality")` :
>  
>   The input is not an igraph object or may not be connected.

Comment: What do you get when you type `class(net)` ?